# Enumerating all the Eulerian paths on edges of cube between 2 points

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

I have been able to enumerate eulerian paths on 3 by 3 square, listing all the non intersecting paths etc. for all 2 different points.

I am having trouble listing all the paths (non intersecting , not passing through the same corner on the edges of the cube) by just pen and paper alone.

Trying to find a way to systematise path enumerations between any 2 points on a given graph.

Let the corners of the cube be numbered from 1 to 8. let the bottom side be numbered 
$$2-3 \\ |\quad| \\ 1-4$$
and the top face 
$$7-6 \\ |\quad| \\ 8-5 $$
then trying to enumerate all the paths from 1 to 6 where no path is traversed twice started to make the following list

$
1236 \\ 
1276 \\
127856 \\
12785436 \\
12781436* \\
12781456* \\
$

But it is getting hard to make sure the above is all the eulerian possible paths starting from 1, the lines with * have the path eulerian passing the vertex 1 twice. Not sure of the should be allowed or not, if there is a name for such paths or how to enumerate them in an algorithmic manner.

is there an algorithmic way, or software that given a graph would produce all eulerian paths between any given 2 points on the graph ( assume small graphs not the huge intractable ones, just want to look at polhydrons).

Comment: Checking wikipedia, in graph theory a simple path has no repeating vertices, so drop the last two. Note that your paths must have an odd number of lines, hence an even number of points in the list. It shouldn't be too difficult to work through systematically. Starting 12 (one of 3 equivalent choices) then 23 (one of 2 equivalent choices) then 36 (the end) or 34, then 45 (only choice) etc. You have 6 equivalent ways of doing the first two steps, so if you follow the possibilities from after that, then multiply by 6 you have a way of checking you got them all.

Comment: @Peter : is there a name for a repeating vertices but not repeating edge (not considering the direction)?

Comment: An Eulerian path is one which uses every edge exactly once. There isn't an Eulerian path for the cube. I'm not sure about a name for a path that can use edges zero times or once, and use vertices multiple times. The easiest thing is just to say what you mean.

Comment: @Peter : Eulerian paths , or Eulerian paths that pass through can pass through a vertex but not any edge. Updating the question

Comment: The problem may be easier to visualise as two concentric squares with 4 lines from the inner to the outer, at adjacent vertices. Think of looking down on a truncated pyramid.

Comment: @Peter, yes, actually that does help with problem , going to look up Eulerian Path Algorithms, most likely I'll find what I need to know under Eulerian paths as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple recursive algorithm would be sufficient to enumerate all $u$-$v$ paths for some vertices $u$ and $v$ where each edge is used at most once. The pseudocode would look like

```
// currentPath is a list of edges
// initially, vertex = u and currentPath = empty list
FindAllPaths(vertex, currentPath): 
    // paths is a list of all 'Eulerian' u-v paths that start with currentPath
    if vertex = v
        paths = currentPath
    else
        paths = empty list

    for each neighbor of vertex such that {vertex, neighbor} not in currentPath:
        add all paths in FindAllPaths(neighbor, currentPath + {vertex, neighbor}) to paths          

    return paths
```

If you want all paths that contain only unique vertices, you should maintain a list of used vertices instead of edges, and check whether a neighbor is not already in this list.